# Why can I not use 2 switch statments in java

Tags: java

So I am trying to write a program to order items.

I must use switch statements to do this but the problem I am having is if I use the switch statement if I try to use a second switch after it also gets called during the first

And even asking for other input after the switch statement should be finished it seems to not call them correctly.

The code I tried is this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int menu = 0;
    int seldelivery = 0;
    double delivery = 0;    
    double selection = 0;
    String name;
    String student;
    String mobile;

    Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);       
    System.out.println("Please select\n1:Coffee\n2:Tea\n3:Quit");
    menu = reader.nextInt();

    switch (menu){
    case 1:
        System.out.println("1 Cappucino €2.00\n2 Latte €2.00\n3 Espresso €1.50\n4 Americano €1.70");
        menu = reader.nextInt();
        if (menu == 1) {
            selection = 2.00;
            System.out.println("You have selected Cappucino");
        } else if (menu == 2) {
            selection = 2.00;
            System.out.println("You have selected Latte");
        } else if (menu == 3) {
            selection = 1.50;
            System.out.println("You have selected Espresso");
        } else if (menu == 4) {
            selection = 1.70;
            System.out.println("You have selected Americano");
        } else {
            System.out.println("inavlid selection please try again");
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        System.out.println("1.Bewley’s Breakfast Tea (Pot for €1.80)\n2.Peppermint €1.50\n3 Camomile  €1.50");
        menu = reader.nextInt();
        if (menu == 1) {
            selection = 1.80;
            System.out.println("You have selected Bewley’s Breakfast Tea");
        } else if (menu == 2) {
            selection = 1.50;
            System.out.println("You have selected Peppermint");
        } else if (menu == 3) {
            selection = 1.50;
            System.out.println("Camomile");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid selection");
        }
        break;
    case 3: //exit
        System.exit(0);
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid selection");
        break;
    }

    System.out.println("Please choose one of the following");
    System.out.println("1 Delivery €1.00 extra");
    System.out.println("2 Pickup at canteen");

    delivery = reader.nextInt();

    switch (seldelivery) {
      case 4:
          System.out.println("1 Delivery will add €1.00");
          break;
      case 5:
          System.out.println("2 Please head to the canteen to collect your order");
          break;
      default:
          System.out.println("Invalid selection");
          break;
    } 

    System.out.println("Please enter your full name including your middle name");
    name = reader.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter your student number");
    student = reader.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter your phone number");
    mobile = reader.nextLine();

    }
}
```

I tried writing the code like this instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int menu = 0;
        int menu1;
        double delivery = 0;
        double selection = 0;
        String name;
        String student;
        String mobile;

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please select\n1:Coffee\n2:Tea\n3:Quit");
        menu = reader.nextInt();

        switch (menu) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("1 Cappucino €2.00\n2 Latte €2.00\n3 Espresso €1.50\n4 Americano €1.70");
                menu = reader.nextInt();
                if (menu == 1) {
                    selection = 2.00;
                    System.out.println("You have selected Cappucino");
                } else if (menu == 2) {
                    selection = 2.00;
                    System.out.println("You have selected Latte");
                } else if (menu == 3) {
                    selection = 1.50;
                    System.out.println("You have selected Espresso");
                } else if (menu == 4) {
                    selection = 1.70;
                    System.out.println("You have selected Americano");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("inavlid selection please try again");
                    menu = reader.nextInt();
                }
                System.out.println("Please choose one of the following\n1 Delivery €1.00 extra\n2 Pickup at canteen");
                menu1 = reader.nextInt();
                switch (menu1) {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("1 Delivery will add €1.00");
                        if (menu1 == 1) {
                            delivery = 1.00;
                            System.out.println("You have selected to have your order delivered");
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("2 Please head to the canteen to collect your order");
                        if (menu1 == 2) {
                            delivery = 0.00;
                            System.out.println("Please head to the canteen to collect your order");
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Invalid selection");
                        break;
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("1.Bewley’s Breakfast Tea (Pot for €1.80)\n2.Peppermint €1.50\n3 Camomile  €1.50");
                menu = reader.nextInt();
                if (menu == 1) {
                    selection = 1.80;
                    System.out.println("You have selected Bewley’s Breakfast Tea");
                } else if (menu == 2) {
                    selection = 1.50;
                    System.out.println("You have selected Peppermint");
                } else if (menu == 3) {
                    System.out.println("Camomile");
                }
                break;
            case 3: //exit
                System.exit(0);
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid selection");
                break;
        }
    }
```

This stops the whole problem with the switches calling when they should not but again if I try to get the strings I need it would print them again to quickly.

The only way I can see doing this is to ask for all the strings needed within the switch and doing all validation as well.

Is this the correct way of doing it or am I missing something here ?

Any help is appreciated thanks :)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend overwriting the variable you are switching over (menu) within the switch itself.  Just an unnecessary source for potential issues.   I'd read over how switches work again as well, there are some glaring issues with how you are using it (cases in second switch, and selDelivery is never set

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand how java syntax is working.

In your second example, you switch on menu:

```
switch (menu) {
  case 1:
  //if you have reached this, then menu is 1 and there is no further need to if on it, because it is 1, nothing else. It is exactly one.

}
```